# Can a multivalued attribute have composite attributues?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I understand the difference between multivalued and composite attributes, but I don't know if a multivalued attribute can have further composite attributes. I think it can, but I never saw an ER diagram like that, even now that I started really looking for it, so I wanted to ask it here.

This is what I had in mind:

[image]

Or how else should I store TV shows with every episode and its title, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would model `Part` as an entity. One way is to make it a weak entity dependent on `TV Show`, and distinguished by `Season` and `Episode`.

[image: TV Show ER Model]

Note this diagram is incomplete without an indication of `TV Show`'s key.